# Gapps ContactsApp timeout for second request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I wrote little Google Apps Script that should get my contacts it looks

```
function myFunction() {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts()
  var contact = contacts[0];
  Logger.log(contact.getFullName());
}
```

When I run it for the first time it works ok (At least it shows me no errors). But next time it gives me an error.

```
[18-02-05 06:55:14:122 PST] Starting execution
[18-02-05 06:55:28:911 PST] ContactsApp.getContacts() [14.782 seconds]
[18-02-05 06:55:28:923 PST] Execution failed: Server error. 
Wait a bit and try again later. (line 2, file "Код") [14.785 seconds total runtime]
```

And I will get this error all the time from now. If I wait for an hour I'll be able to make one more 'good' request and then again an error.

UPD: If I will copy this code to a new google account that has only 5 contacts stored - it will work.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#common_errors

There is a bug in Google Apps Script that is causing this error. Report the error on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).